# Can airtags be tracked from an iMac desktop, with no iPhone?

Tags: imac, airtag

I don't have an iPhone, but I want to use Apple airtags to track my bicycle, and other high value goods.   Can I get all the airtag tracking capability from an iMac desktop?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can [track an AirTag](https://support.apple.com/guide/findmy-mac/locate-an-item-fmmc686ad7a1/3.0/mac/13.0) with your Mac, but you [can't set it up](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253368697) unless you have an iOS device.

Verbatim tracking instructions transcribed and formatted below, taken from the Apple Support link above:

### Track

**See the location of an item**

1. In the Find My app  on your Mac, click Items.

- Tip: If an item’s battery level is low, a low battery icon appears next to its name in the Items list. See the Apple Support article [How to replace the battery in your AirTag.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211670)

2. In the Items list, select the item you want to locate.

- *If the item can be located*: It appears on the map so you can see where it is. The updated location and timestamp appear under the item’s name. If there’s a blue circle around the item, the location is approximate.
- *If the item can’t be located*: Below the item’s name, “No location found” appears. If you want to be notified when the location is available, click the Info button  on the map, then select Notify When Found. You receive a notification once it’s located.

**Important**: Make sure you allow notifications for the Find My app. See [Change Notifications settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-notifications-settings-mh40583/mac).

Comment: follow up question: is there any technical reason why you can't set it up, but you can track it? Or is this just Apple trying to make sure that you own _all_ of their ecosystem before they reward you in your RL quest with FULL Airtag Power. Just have MacBook and an Airtag? https://media.giphy.com/media/eJ4j2VnYOZU8qJU3Py/giphy.gif

Comment: You can only connect with the NFC (Bluetooth) in the iDevice to register the tag - that's how Apple coded it. Although we all know modern Macs have Bluetooth, pairing AirTags hasn't been enabled through macOS, although the code probably exists. There's a [Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/airtag/) page just for AirTags. I just requested a future enhancement to be able to activate AirTags with a Mac. That's the best I can do, and trying to figure out why Apple does the things it does is an exercise in futility most of the time.